# How do I make a violin plots of gene expression data when my y-values need to be converted to numerical values first?

Tags: r, ggplot2, character, numeric, violin-plot

I have a gene expression dataset for many genes per several conditions. Focussing on one condition, ("DD" for DMSO DMSO), I made a file called "DD_violin_subset" with a table of the enzymes and their expression (TPS) like this:

| enzyme | TPS |
| --- | --- |
| A4GALT | 0,705748 |
| AACS | 39,42209 |
| AADAT | 3,619634 |
| AAK1 | 16,64294 |
| AARS1 | 566,514 |

I would like to make a violinplot of this data but it kept giving me errors.

I already tried several things:

```
>DD_violin_subset <- fread("C:\\Users\\maris\\Desktop\\DD_violin_subset.csv")

> names(DD_violin_subset)
[1] "enzyme" "TPS"   

> str(DD_violin_subset)
Classes ‘data.table’ and 'data.frame':  5 obs. of  2 variables:
 $ enzyme: chr  "A4GALT" "AACS" "AADAT" "AAK1" ...
 $ TPS   : chr  "0,705747614" "39,42209011" "3,619633792" "16,64293604" ...
 - attr(*, ".internal.selfref")=<externalptr>
```

As you can see, it reads TPS as a character, even though it should be read as numerical values. I think this is what is causing my errors so I tried to write them as numerical values:

```
> ggplot(DD_violin_subset, aes(y= as.numeric(TPM)))+geom_violin()
Error in `geom_violin()`:
! Problem while computing aesthetics.
ℹ Error occurred in the 1st layer.
Caused by error in `FUN()`:
! object 'TPM' not found
Run `rlang::last_trace()` to see where the error occurred.
```

So I thought, since TMP is not found, maybe I should specify the dataset again?

````
>ggplot(DD_violin_subset, aes(y= as.numeric(DD_violin_subset$TPM)))+geom_violin()
Error in `geom_violin()`:
Problem while computing aesthetics.
Error occurred in the 1st layer.
Caused by error in `check_aesthetics()`:
Aesthetics must be either length 1 or the same
as the data (5)
Fix the following mappings: `y`
Run `rlang::last_trace()` to see where the error occurred.
> ```

But no. TPS keeps on being "not found" and they're still read as characters whist they shoud be numericals. I fear this might be the reason why I can't get my plots, but I might be totally in the wrong. I'm new to R and would really appreciate your help! Anyone any ideas how I could get my violinplots? 

Thanks a lot for you help and effort!
````

Comment: You have `TPS` in your `DD_violin_subset` but you give `TPM` in ggplot

Comment: If your comma is the decimal separator then you can use `df$TPS <- as.numeric(sub(",", ".", df$TPS, fixed = TRUE))`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, you are right that you need to convert TPS to numeric. This can be done with `as.numeric` but preferably you would specify the `dec` argument to read commas as decimal.

You would probably want something like this.
`fread(path, dec = ",")`

Second and third, you are not specifying your X axis in your ggplot function. So how should the violin plots be separated? And you don't need the `$` notation in a ggplot call as tidyverse uses data masking. So the following should be enough.

`ggplot(data = DD_violin_subset, aes(x = enzyme, y = TPS)) + geom_violin()`

Comment: fread(path, dec = ",") helped me a lot and I managed to get my violin plot. Thank you so much for your help! :)